# Loopings In VB.NET (FOR EACH)

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach, vb.net-2010

I am currently making a program in vb.net. 
it has lots of Text box inside of it.
how do i clear them using for each loop.

I have here my code but nothing happens in my program, my text boxes still have data.

```
For Each txt As TextBox In personalInfo.Controls
            txt.Enabled = False
Next
```

by the way i have three group boxes with text boxes how do i clear all of text boxes with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
txt.Clear();
```

for clearing a TextBox. Are you sure that all controls in personalInfo are TextBoxes? If not, use

```
For Each txt In personalInfo.Controls
   If TypeOf (txt) Is TextBox Then
      txt.Clear()
   End If
Next
```

Comment: what if, i want it to be disabled?

Comment: txt.Enabled = False so that one was ok.

Comment: thank you! one more thing how bout in form i do have 2 panel and in  first panel has 3 groupbox, how do i disable textboxes inside the groupbox

Comment: That I do not know by heart.

Comment: You can access the controls in the same way directly by the groupbox without referencing the panel: For Each txt in <GroupBoxName>.Controls. So if the name of the GroupBox is MyGroupBox: For Each txt in MyGroupBox.Controls.