# How to do a loop for each item in a list? VB.NET

Tags: file, foreach, streamwriter

How do i do a loop for each item in a list?

I tried to do a `For Each` but then i could not get it past that.

i know it has to end with: `Next` but i dont know how to make a loop for each item, which is the main problem.

to give further information, i am writing an item of the list to a text file, and every item it needs to get the "n" item of the list and write it.

What i am doing:

````
For Each In listclass.List

    usernameFile.WriteLine(usersClass.UsersName(n))
    usernameFile.Close()

Next```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the VB.net microsoft docs? It appears you're missing the "Element" portion in your first "For Each..." statement. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement). Also, try searching for existing answers on stackoverflow. Often times, a question has already been answered as in the following: [Looping in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195374/3324451)